# iteration an object and hasownproperty

Tags: javascript, object

I was looking at a clone object function here:

http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/2

the function is:

```
function clone(obj) {
    var target = {};
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            target[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

and i was wondering why is the check

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
```

needed ?

Because if property **i** is not in the object **obj**, it wouldn't be iterated in the first place in the **for** loop.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Could be inherited from prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for...in` construct also loops over inherited properties.

If you create an object with a constructor, for example like this :

```
var s = new String();
```

then you have all enumerable `String` functions listed among the properties, but not as **own** properties (i.e. direct properties). For example try this in the console :

```
for (var k in s) console.log(k)
```

You'll discover a few interesting functions that were probably indispensable to SO developers like `formatUnicorn`.

This check lets you clone direct enumerable properties without cloning the prototype properties.

See [documentation on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: @JanDvorak Every function you add is enumerable, sometimes - especially in older implementations you might want to use hasOwnPropertyName to filter things on the prototype.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yep, but most of the functions are pre-existing and thus not enumerable. Definitely not "all String functions" are enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Because the original loop will also show properties from the prototype object, which you wouldn't want.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that as of JavaScript 1.8.5 you can use `Object.keys(obj)` to get an Array of properties defined on the object itself 
(ones that return true for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`).

This is better (and readable) than using for-in loop.

Its supported on these browsers:

- Firefox (Gecko): 4 (2.0)
- Chrome: 5
- Internet Explorer: 9

More info on 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys